# AWS: encrypted ROOT EBS doesn't support t2 instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ebs

I created an AMI from my web server. Then I copied the snapshot, checking the "encrypted" checkbox. Then I created an AMI from this encrypted snapshot. Then I tried to launch a new instance from this new encrypted AMI. I was stunned to find that t2 instance types are are disabled, and only m3.medium or above are allowed.

Is it supposed to be the case, or I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out - I chose PV instead of HVM as "Virtualization type". If I choose HVM all instance types would be supported.